# Why is Cassandra taking this much memory, despite -Xmx heap option?

Tags: java, cassandra, heap-memory

I'm running Cassandra (a Java process) on my server, which has limited memory. I edit Cassandra's configuration (`config/jvm.options`) to pass these arguments to the Java virtual machine, to limit the heap size.

```
-Xms180M -Xmx180M
```

I can see them in the output of `ps ax | grep java`, which shows:

```
[...] /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java [...] 
   -Xms180M -Xmx180M [...] org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

But it seems to use a lot more than 180MB, and another server process keeps disappearing. I'm guessing that the kernel is killing the other process because of limited memory.

Here is a piece of the screen in `top`:

```
KiB Mem :  1009128 total,    87072 free,   643488 used,   278568 buff/cach
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   222228 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                 
20410 cassand+  20   0 2048132 433828   8456 S  0.3 43.0  41:25.22 java
```

Doesn't the `RES 433828` mean than there is 433 MB of RAM being used by Cassandra? Does that seem possible, after I supposedly limited the Java heap to 180 MB?  If the heap is limited to 180 MB, what is taking the other 433-180 = 253MB? And can I limit that too?

Comment: _"my server, which has limited memory"_ - Assuming this is a work-related question, the monetary value of the time you've already spent on this far exceeds the cost of additional memory.  When servers have dozens of gigabytes of memory, worrying about a few hundred MB is not cost effective.

Comment: Yes, this is one reason Jeff Bezos is rich. :) It’s more of a personal project, though that could change. I may upgrade my Digital Ocean server, but I’d like to understand the problem first, so it doesn’t simply use up the additional RAM and leave me in the same spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra has an on-heap portion (controlled by -Xmx) and an off-heap portion. Most of the off-heap data structures typically scale with data size - things like the partition index, bloom filter, and compression chunk data are stored in direct memory regions and increase with disk usage.

You can tune these somewhat, but they're less obvious and have performance tradeoffs. For example, raising the `bloom_filter_fp_chance` from `0.01` to `0.1` will use significantly less memory, but you may read extra sstables on the read path.

Comment: Okay. Maybe this is a separate question, but is there a way to constrain this off-heap portion to a certain memory size? If not, I'm confused, because a large database could start crashing a server (causing OOM kills). I'd rather have my system slow down, or log warnings saying that it would like more RAM, rather than killing random processes.

Comment: Not really, no. You can set `XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`, but that just makes you OOM at the JVM level instead of the server level.  It's worth a JIRA to ask for a way to cap it, but the reality is that data structures are setup to be offheap, so if you have so much data that we can't make the data structure offheap, we'd still have to crash the DB.

Comment: You said "scale with data size". I assume that means data size on the node, not data size of the complete database. Would it be accurate then to say that the way to manage the RAM on my servers is to simply observe how much RAM Cassandra uses, and either 1. choose servers with enough RAM to give it room, or 2. create more nodes to split the data across more servers and (hopefully) decrease the RAM requirements of a single node?

Comment: Yes to both of those